# Changing mod_rewrite "file exists" checks to not see directories as files

Tags: apache, webserver, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite rules set up:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This works fine, allowing me to use "nice" URIs (like www.mysite.com/about instead of www.mysite.com/about.php.

However, when I have both a directory and a file with the same name (for example /products and products.php, this breaks as apache just redirects to the directory. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, but that's going to effectively disable your ability to browse directories or to load a `DirectoryIndex` page.

Comment: That does not seem to have any effect on my apache behaviour. I just took out that line completely, but it is still indexing the folder contents instead of going for the php file.